# How to return multiple INSERTED ID's in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function which takes two arguments, the first one is an integer and the second one is an array of varchars.

I want to insert just the hashes that aren't previously inserted for the campaign and then return the inserted ids — in this case, the `url_hash` field of the `campaigns_urls` table — but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "hash" does not exist LINE 10:  RETURNING "hash"
                    ^ 
HINT:  There is a column named "hash" in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

I am calling a function like this:

```
-- SELECT * FROM assign_urls_to_campaign(1,'{Xelgb20Lw}')

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.assign_urls_to_campaign(
    param_campaign_id integer,
    param_hashes character varying(20)[]
)
    RETURNS character varying(20)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO campaigns_urls ("campaign_id", "url_hash") 
    SELECT
        param_campaign_id as "id", "P"."hash"
    FROM "urls" AS "U"
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT hash FROM UNNEST(param_hashes) AS "hash"
    ) AS "P"
    ON "U"."hash" = "P"."hash"
    WHERE "U"."hash" ISNULL
    RETURNING "hash";

END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: I think you're going to need a correlated subquery or CTE or somesuch for this.  Intuitively I think that right outer join might be causing the problem.

Comment: You probably want `RETURNING url_hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more issues:

1. If functions returns more than one row, then should to use `SETOF` keywords after `RETURNS`.
2. PlpgSQL functions requires `RETURN` statement - in this case `RETURN QUERY`.

   ```
   create table test(a int);

   create or replace function foo(int)
   returns setof int as $$
   begin
     return query
       insert into test 
         select v from generate_series(1,$1) g(v)
         returning a;
   end;
   $$ language plpgsql;

   postgres=# select * from foo(3);
   ┌─────┐
   │ foo │
   ╞═════╡
   │   1 │
   │   2 │
   │   3 │
   └─────┘
   (3 rows)
   ```

Comment: You were right, it was my mistake not realizing about the missing `SETOF` and I didn't new I could do a `RETURN QUERY INSERT ... RETURNING id`, works as expected.